# How does the sampling distribution of a statistic relate to the t or z distribution?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, sampling, inference, standard-error

My understanding of the output of statistical models is that you get a sample estimate. E.g. in regression you'd get a slope among other things.

This estimate is one of many possible slopes that come from your sampling distribution of sample slopes which has a mean of 0 under the null hypothesis. The standard error is the standard deviation of this sampling distribution.

I know that dividing the statistic by the SE you get your t or z statistic from which you can use to calculate the p-value. Now, my question is - **is the t or z distribution just a standardized sampling distribution of the sample statistic that accounts for the sample size/ degrees of freedom?**

I have two distributions in my mind, one made up of the 'raw' statistics and one made up of the t-statistics.

Thanks

Comment: I assume you mean the normal/Gaussian distribution when you talk about the z distribution? Z is a letter often used for the Gaussian test statistic, but it isn't the name of the distribution.

Comment: Yes, so a z distribution is a standard normal distribution and a t distribution is one that has heavier tails.

Comment: The justification for a $t$-statistic is that the raw statistic (sample mean or estimated slope or whatever) may have an approximately normal distribution, and then takes into account that the standard error of that statistic is estimated from the data rather than known from the start (a more substantial issue when the number of degrees of freedom is small).  The assumption that the statistic has an approximately normal distribution does not mean that the individual observations do too.